# Azure Functions Core Tools fails to start: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider')

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

When attempting to start my Azure Functions project in local debug mode in Visual Studio Code on my dev box on prem, I receive the following error:

```
[2024-03-01T20:11:07.673Z] Error building configuration in an external startup class.
[2024-03-01T20:11:07.675Z] Error building configuration in an external startup class. System.Net.Http: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. (functionscdn.azureedge.net:443). System.Net.Sockets: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
[2024-03-01T20:11:07.732Z] A host error has occurred during startup operation 'cb26a4d1-0d3d-492f-8b7f-e04cff13d48e'.
[2024-03-01T20:11:07.733Z] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: Error building configuration in an external startup class. System.Net.Http: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. (functionscdn.azureedge.net:443). System.Net.Sockets: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider')
```

Looking at the [Azure Services networking requirements for Visual Studio behind a firewall](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/install-and-use-visual-studio-behind-a-firewall-or-proxy-server?view=vs-2022#use-visual-studio-and-azure-services), I can see that `functionscdn.azureedge.net` access is used "for checking for updated versions of the Azure Functions CLI."

How can I disable this behavior to enable me to debug my Azure Functions project without making this network change?

Answer (score 0):

There is no Azure Functions Extension config to disable this check. However, removing the `extensionBundle` section from `host.json` resolves this issue.

More details provided by @offbeatful on GitHub:

> Why does this work?
>
> It seems there is a code introduced in src/Azure.Functions.Cli/Actions/HostActions/Startup.cs that will check if `extensionBundle` is defined and if it is, it will set environment variables to check for latest version.
>
> ```cs
> private void SetBundlesEnvironmentVariables()
> {
>     var bundleId = ExtensionBundleHelper.GetExtensionBundleOptions(_hostOptions).Id;
>     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(bundleId))
>     {
>         Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("AzureFunctionsJobHost__extensionBundle__downloadPath", ExtensionBundleHelper.GetBundleDownloadPath(bundleId));
>         Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("AzureFunctionsJobHost__extensionBundle__ensureLatest", "true");
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> That code was actually introduced as part of another issues:
>
> ```cs
>   // workaround for https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/2097
>   SetBundlesEnvironmentVariables();
> ```
>
> I am running javascript functions and I confirmed that this section is not required for Development Model 4 when deploying in Azure. So `extensionBundle` section can be safely removed.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/2060